# Does glx and xrandr version belong to client \'s hardware on remote desktop environment?

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, xorg, glx, xrandr

I am in an environment where computer use is ristricted. So I rented a computer on the internet(Like Aamazon EC2) to bypass restriction, develop software.
I tried

1. Install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64bit
2. Install xfce4, tightvnc for build remote desktop environment
3. Install apache guacamole, nginx to bypass restriction

There were a lot of challenges, but in the end It became a nice Remote Desktop Environment that using only 443 port.

But I faced new challenges. Everytime when I lauch some program, I see the messages below.

> gl_surface_glx.cc(460)] GLX 1.3 or later is required.
>
> This system is using RandR 1.1. For the display settings to work version 1.2 is required at least

Even after changing the computer serveral times(virtual computer, bare-metal computer, with or without graphic card) , the result was the same. I updated upgraded everything I can, but always face below

> $ xrandr --version
>
> xrandr program version       1.5.0
>
> Server reports RandR version 1.1

and

> $ glxinfo
>
> ...
>
> server glx version string: 1.2
>
> ...
>
> client glx version string: 1.4

Why do server always return low version of something?

Answer (score 0):

The X server is on your local machine, and your remote computer acts as X client that sends instructions to the server (local machine) to render graphics.

Comment: You mean my computer draw everything regradless of the performance of remote computer? I want to my remote server render everything and send pixel information to my computer.